# Converting two formats of timestamp with two_datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a dataset where timestamps are in two distinct formats...
`Tue Oct 30 12:57:49 +0000 2012` and
`Tue Mar 11 13: 57: 22 +0000 2014`
I would like to parse these into a pd.datetime format.

My approach so far has been to parse one type (with errors='ignore' so that non-matching timestamps aren't touched), then to parse the second time with the other format.

```py
train['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(train['timestamp'], format='%a %b %d %H: %M: %S %z %Y', errors='ignore')
train['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(train['timestamp'], format='%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y')
```

I seem to get an error during the second call for a timestamp I would have expected to be 'picked up' by the first expression:

`ValueError: time data 'Tue Mar 11 23: 59: 22 +0000 2014' does not match format '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y' (match)`

I would have thought `Tue Mar 11 23: 59: 22 +0000 2014` would have been matched by `%a %b %d %H: %M: %S %z %Y` in the first line, so the second line wouldn't be shown this format.

Comment: Not sure about this, but it seems to me a way to solve it would be to just remove all spaces: `pd.to_datetime(train['timestamp'].str.replace(' ',''), format='%a%b%d%H:%M:%S%z%Y')`

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot. A much nicer solution than that which I was trying to do. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking a the output of these two calls we can see that the parsing workes, but that pandas converts the timestamp object back to a string when getting mixed data (timestamp for successful, str for errors)

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {
'timestamp':  ['Tue Oct 30 12:57:49 +0000 2012','Tue Mar 11 13: 57: 22 +0000 2014']
}
train = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data1)

list(map(type, pd.to_datetime(train['timestamp'], format='%a %b %d %H: %M: %S %z %Y', errors='ignore'))) #=> ['str','str']
```

We can see that the parsing worked fine by running:

```
pd.to_datetime(train['timestamp'], format='%a %b %d %H: %M: %S %z %Y', errors='coerce')
```

where one failed and one succeeded (and returned NaT)

The solution is to either convert to same format using:

```
pd.to_datetime(train['timestamp'].str.replace(' ',''), format='%a%b%d%H:%M:%S%z%Y')
```

or run two separate parsings and combine:

```
t1 = pd.to_datetime(train['timestamp'], format='%a %b %d %H: %M: %S %z %Y', errors='coerce')
t2 = pd.to_datetime(train['timestamp'], format='%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y', errors='coerce')
train['timestamp'] = t1.combine_first(t2)
```

Comment: Very nice, thanks for explaining why it didn't work properly. I like the combine_first function, I didn't know that existed.